# Finding the biggest number for a sequence given by the while loop

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, while-loop

I'm currently learning Python, more specifically, how the loop while works. As far as I know, this loop can be used to create sequences of numbers with and specific condition. For example,

```
n=1

while n < 10:
    n = n*2
    print(n)
```

Which gives the powers of two up to 16:

```
2
4
8
16
```

But I was wondering if there's a way for the loop to print only the biggest number of the sequence, in this case, it would be 16. Here's my attempt,

```
n=1
bigNumber = 0
while n <= 10:
    bigNumber = n
    n = n*2
    if n < bigNumber:
        print(bigNumber)
```

However it doesn't work. Could someone point out were the mistake is?

Comment: Print `n` after the while loop has finished?

Comment: but if I do that ,the console prints 2, 4, 8, 16 and not only 16. so the if statement should be iterated in while?

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't work as intended because the condition of the `if` statement is never fulfilled. Just take for example `n=4`. Then in the loop you first assign `bigNumber = 4` and then `n` is increased to `8`. And at this point, always `n > bigNumber`.

The easiest way here to get the correct answer is to print `n` after the loop (already mentioned in a comment) as `n` is always incrementing.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in 2 ways.

If you just want to print the final value you can just ommit part of the code:

```
n=1

while n < 10:
    n = n*2

print(n)
```

If you want to keep all values and then show the highest one:

```
n=1
num_list = []

while n < 10:
    num_list.append(n)
    n = n*2

print(f'From the numbers {num_list} the highest is {max(num_list)}')
```

The `max()` function is built to find the highest value in a list.

The output should be:

```
From the numbers [1, 2, 4, 8] the highest is 8
```

Comment: I see,  but know I don't understand  ( for the first way) why it printed out 16. Wasn't it supposed to print all the values? I mean, does printing n immediately stops the loop?

Comment: @nutshell_A The loop stops when the condition is false i.e. `n>=10`. The `print` function is outside of the loop. It prints after the loop operation is finished.

Comment: I get it know, thx for the extra explanation!

Answer (score 0):

`print` the number after the `while` loop is finished.

```
n=1
bigNumber = 0
while n <= 10:
    bigNumber = n
    n = n*2
print(bigNumber)
```